# API Expose (NodeJS/ExpressJS)

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, security, express

I'm writing a website on Express. Handling routes using express router. I have some routes: registration, login, upload, and so on. As `upload` route expects files, in front-end I use ajax to upload files to `upload` route. The question is: am I allowed to reveal route names in front end. As in front end:`$.post('upload')...`

Comment: Yes. Why wouldn't you?

Comment: I don't feel like, though that's first time meaking serious website, that's why I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call routes with ajax, somelike this...

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: '/route',
            success: function(ret) {
                // here its possible to get the return of res.send() from server
            }
        });
```

But, one tip for to use **upload** with express: search for [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) and [formidable-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable-upload) for facility your work, somelike [this](http://inversekarma.in/technology/howto/uploading-files-in-nodejs-express-4-using-formidable/) =]

Comment: Thanks! So doing something like your example - letting know for clients about API keys is not a security issue right? (Only if API itself is secured)

Comment: Not is a security issue, it's normal use